# waitForElementVisible timesout even though element in there

Tags: nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I'm trying to use waitForElementVisible, but that times out even though the element is on the page.

```
browser.waitForElementVisible('.splash-buttons');
```

I'm running it on IE11 Windows 8.1 on the saucelabs IE driver.

Comment: Can you post some log output with the --verbose flag?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
browser.waitForElementPresent('.splash-buttons',30000,false,function(result){
     if(result.value === true){
            browser.waitForElementVisible('.splash-buttons');
         } else {
        browser.pause();
       // there element is not there ,let debug here     
       }
    });
```